# NuSoap equivalent of SoapVar()

Tags: php, web-services, soap, nusoap

I don't know much about NuSoap, but unfortunately I *have* to use it.
I'm trying to follow example code for the dotmailer web service api [Here](http://www.dotmailer.co.uk/api/address_books/add_contact_to_address_book.aspx). I need to be able to add custom fields for subscribers.

In the example code custom/additional fields are defined like so;

```
new SoapVar($FirstName,XSD_STRING,"string","http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
```

Heres the code I have right now;

```
<?php
function subscribeUserEmail($email)
{   
    $username = "********";
    $password = "********";
    $postURL  = "http://apiconnector.com/api.asmx?WSDL";

    $contact = array (
        "Email" => $email,
        "AudienceType" => "B2C",
        "OptInType" => "Single",
        "EmailType" => "Html",
        "ID" => -1,
        "DataFields" => array(
            "Keys" => array("TEST"),
            "Values" => array("Name")
        )
    );
    $params = array(
        "username" => $username,
        "password" => $password,
        "contact" => $contact,
        "addressbookId" => "******"
    );

    $client = new soapclient($postURL, true);
    $error = $client->getError();
    $result = $client->call('AddContactToAddressBook', $params);

    echo "<h2>Request</h2>";
    print("<pre>".$client->request."</pre>");

    echo "<h2>Response</h2>";
    print("<pre>".$client->response."</pre>");

    echo "<h2>Debug</h2>";
    print("<pre>".$client->debug_str."</pre>");
}
?>
```

If the `$contact` array is changed to this;

```
$contact = array (
    "Email" => $email,
    "AudienceType" => "B2C",
    "OptInType" => "Single",
    "EmailType" => "Html",
    "ID" => -1,
    "DataFields" => array(
        "Keys" => array("TEST"),
        "Values" => array(new SoapVar("Name",XSD_STRING,"string","http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema") )
    )
);
```

And used with a regular soap client, the code works. So I'm pretty sure there aren't any other problems with my function.

I've tried using the following;

```
new soapval("string", XSD_STRING, "Name","http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
```

As an alternative to the SoapVar() method, but I get the same errors as if I entered the value as plain text.

How can I replicate the functionality of SoapVar() in NuSoap? This appears to be the only issue.

Comment: Searching for the same , have u got any Solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I ended up having to host the script on a separate website that allowed me to use standard `SOAP` functions. I had to give up on a `NuSOAP` version of the above.